# If test fails in before/bforeEach hook will there be a guarantee that following tests won't be launched?

Tags: mocha.js, cypress

Let me give a context.
Imagine, before all tests I want to receive a definite value. Without this value all my tests won't pass.
The value is recieved through http request.

So my thought is to make that request in before hook and check  that I got the value I expected.

The question is:
if assertion in before hook fails, will it guarantee that all following tests will be skipped ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the tests on the same level as the hook will be skipped.

You can quickly try this out in the test runner:

```
describe('some feature', () => {
  before(() => { expect(false).eq(true) })
  it('should be skipped', () => { expect(true).eq(true) })
  it('should also be skipped', () => { expect(true).eq(true) })
})
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I formulated it wrong. I meant lets say my tests use definite value which I got  in before or beforeaeach hook and got it through http request. Run each it block wirhoit this value doesnt have sense.Is it a good idea to check whether this value from http request is valid in before hook?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the following tests will be skipped.

In those cases I see an error: **"Because this error occurred during a 'before each' hook we are skipping the remaining tests in the current suite: 'test_1'"**